# How can I SHA512 a string in C#?

Tags: c#, hash

I am trying to write a function to take a string and sha512 it like so?

```
public string SHA512(string input)
{
     string hash;

     ~magic~

     return hash;
}
```

What should the magic be?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Your code is correct, but you should dispose of the SHA512Managed instance:

```
using (SHA512 shaM = new SHA512Managed())
{
   hash = shaM.ComputeHash(data);
}
```

512 bits are 64 bytes.

To convert a string to a byte array, you need to specify an encoding. UTF8 is okay if you want to create a hash code:

```
var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("text");    
using (...
```

Comment: The number of examples that don't utilize dispose in any fashion whatsoever is astounding. Kudos for showing the idiomatic manner with `using`.

Comment: Instead of `var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(foo)`, use `var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(foo)`.

Comment: Why do you need the "using" clause? Won't the default C# garbage collection kick in and get rid of the shaM variable? Why is explicit garbage collection like this necessary?

Comment: Do not mix up carbage collection and freeing/disposing unused unmanaged objects. Using "using" makes sure that Dispose is called when the using block ends. This will release unmanaged resources - otherwise they will be released when the GC cleans up the object (and calls the finalizer internally). The class SHA512Managed is disposable, so I prefer to use using.

For more information about the Dispose pattern, take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: In .NET 6 it throws warning `Warning SYSLIB0021  'SHA512Managed' is obsolete:
'Derived cryptographic types are obsolete.
Use the Create method on the base type instead.'` How to use this in .NET 6 ? There is separate question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70109573/how-to-calculate-sha-512-hash-properly-in-net-6

Answer (score 44):

This is from one of my projects:

```
public static string SHA512(string input)
{
    var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
    using (var hash = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512.Create())
    {
        var hashedInputBytes = hash.ComputeHash(bytes);

        // Convert to text
        // StringBuilder Capacity is 128, because 512 bits / 8 bits in byte * 2 symbols for byte 
        var hashedInputStringBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder(128);
        foreach (var b in hashedInputBytes)
            hashedInputStringBuilder.Append(b.ToString("X2"));
        return hashedInputStringBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Please, note:

1. SHA512 object is disposed ('using' section), so we do not have any resource leaks.
2. StringBuilder is used for efficient hex string building.

Comment: The StringBuilder code can  be replaced by a single line
 
‘var hash = BitConverter.ToString(hashedInputBytes).Replace("-", "");’
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 8):

`512/8 = 64`, so 64 is indeed the correct size. Perhaps you want to convert it to hexadecimal *after* the SHA512 algorithm.

See also: [How do you convert Byte Array to Hexadecimal String, and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa-in-c)

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I just used an online generator to compare against, which made hex. Thanks :)

Comment: The link does not convert a string to a byte array, it converts hex string to bytes. To convert a string to a byte array, use something like `Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount("text")`

Comment: @CarstenSchütte Well, UTF-8 is for text encoding, which is not related to this question. And either way, GetByteCount wouldn't convert the string to a byte array. It'd only get the *length* of the byte array.

Comment: @CarstenSchütte Oh, wait. I think I know what you meant. You're talking about obtaining the initial "data" variable, right? In that case, yes, UTF-8 is fine. Still, GetByteCount is still not the appropriate function.

Comment: @luiscubal: Sorry, GetByteCount was my fault (and copy/paste error). Of course you need to use GetBytes() to get the data.

Answer (score 4):

You might try these lines:

```
public static string GenSHA512(string s, bool l = false)
{
    string r = "";

    try
    {
        byte[] d = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);

        using (SHA512 a = new SHA512Managed())
        {
            byte[] h = a.ComputeHash(d);
            r = BitConverter.ToString(h).Replace("-", "");
        }

        r = (l ? r.ToLowerInvariant() : r);
    }
    catch
    {

    }

    return r;
}
```

1. It is disposed at the end
2. It's safe
3. Supports lower case

Answer (score 2):

Instead of WinCrypt-API using System.Security.Cryptography, you can also use BouncyCastle:

```
public static byte[] SHA512(string text)
{
    byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);

    Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Digests.Sha512Digest digester = new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Digests.Sha512Digest();
    byte[] retValue = new byte[digester.GetDigestSize()];
    digester.BlockUpdate(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    digester.DoFinal(retValue, 0);
    return retValue;
}
```

If you need the HMAC-version (to add authentication to the hash)

```
public static byte[] HmacSha512(string text, string key)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);

    var hmac = new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Macs.HMac(new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Digests.Sha512Digest());
    hmac.Init(new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.KeyParameter(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key)));

    byte[] result = new byte[hmac.GetMacSize()];
    hmac.BlockUpdate(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    hmac.DoFinal(result, 0);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: what is BouncyCastle?

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder: The Bouncy Castle Crypto APIs are looked after by an Australian Charity, the Legion of the Bouncy Castle Inc., which looks after the care and feeding of the Bouncy Castle APIs.  https://www.bouncycastle.org/

Answer (score 2):

I used the following

```
public static string ToSha512(this string inputString)
{
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputString)) return string.Empty;
        using (SHA512 shaM = new SHA512Managed())
        {
            return Convert.ToBase64String(shaM.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputString)));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Keeping it simple:

```
using (SHA512 sha512 = new SHA512Managed())
{
    password = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(sha512.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are expecting 128.

8 bits in a byte. 64 bytes. 8 * 64 = 512 bit hash.

Answer (score 1):

From the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed.aspx):
The hash size for the SHA512Managed algorithm is 512 bits.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512 class

[MSDN on SHA512](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha512)

Here is an example, straigt from the MSDN

```
byte[] data = new byte[DATA_SIZE];
byte[] result;
SHA512 shaM = new SHA512Managed();
result = shaM.ComputeHash(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Made it into an extension method in my ExtensionUtility.cs class

```
public static string SHA512(this string plainText)
    {
      
        using (SHA512 shaM = new SHA512Managed())
        {
            var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
            var hashedInputBytes = shaM.ComputeHash(buffer);

           return BitConverter.ToString(hashedInputBytes).Replace("-", "");

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Update:

`new SHA512Managed()` is depricated and `SHA512.Create()` should be used instead.

There is also a **static** Function availible since .NET5+.
The static Version is slightly faster and allocates less Memory compared to `SHA512.Create()`.

So the last up to date version would be:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace Common;
public class Hash
{
    public static string Sha512(string text) => Convert.ToHexString(SHA512.HashData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text)));

    public static string Sha512(byte[] data) => Convert.ToHexString(SHA512.HashData(data));
}
```

Note: this functions are **ThreadSafe**.

This will return an uppercase 128 Byte-long Hexstring (each of the 64 Bytes is represented by 2 Byte (00 - FF).

So this code:

```
var theHash = Common.Hash.Sha512("this is to be hashed");
```

would result in:

```
3C1E5B4C27F3FD8D297000A74FFA04B0EA310E61E7043E85CB9EFDE55C00E730549D76DBB97864A4791F40DA27C4C292E40EF76BCEE5E88CAEA6E48E79E635B5
```

if you want to do some performance test on you own you can use this:

```
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace PerformanceTests
{
    [MemoryDiagnoser]
    [Orderer(BenchmarkDotNet.Order.SummaryOrderPolicy.FastestToSlowest)]
    [RankColumn]
    public class Hashes
    {
        private string _inputText;
        private byte[] _inputByte;

        [Params(1_000, 10_000)]
        public int N;

        [GlobalSetup]
        public void Setup()
        {
            const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            _inputText = new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, N).Select(s => s[new Random().Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());

            _inputByte = new byte[N];
            new Random(42).NextBytes(_inputByte);
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public string Sha512StaticInputString() => Convert.ToHexString(SHA512.HashData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_inputText)));

        [Benchmark]
        public string Sha512NonStaticInputString()
        {
            using var sha512 = SHA512.Create();
            return Convert.ToHexString(sha512.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_inputText)));
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public string Sha512StaticInputByte() => Convert.ToHexString(SHA512.HashData(_inputByte));

        [Benchmark]
        public string Sha512NonStaticInputByte()
        {
            using var sha512 = SHA512.Create();
            return Convert.ToHexString(sha512.ComputeHash(_inputByte));
        }
    }
}
```

results on my machine:[image]
Note: **N** is the len of the input data in bytes.

Answer (score 0):

```
UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();            
        byte[] message = UE.GetBytes(password);
        SHA512Managed hashString = new SHA512Managed();
        string hexNumber = "";
        byte[]  hashValue = hashString.ComputeHash(message);
        foreach (byte x in hashValue)
        {
            hexNumber += String.Format("{0:x2}", x);
        }
        string hashData = hexNumber;
```