# How to calculate sha 512 hash properly in .NET 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cryptography, sha, sha512, .net-6.0

In .NET 6 code from [How can I SHA512 a string in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367727/how-can-i-sha512-a-string-in-c)

```
  var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("key");
  byte[] hash;
  using (SHA512 shaM = new SHA512Managed())
    hash = shaM.ComputeHash(data);
```

Throws warning

```
Warning SYSLIB0021  'SHA512Managed' is obsolete:
'Derived cryptographic types are obsolete.
Use the Create method on the base type instead.'
```

Visual Studio 2022 does not offer code changes for this.
How to replace this code with proper code in .NET 6 ?

Code is called from ASP.NET MVC controller.

Comment: Why not as recommended in the warning: `SHA512 shaM = SHA512.Create()` with `System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512`?

Comment: thank you, it removes the warning. You can wrote this as answer

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
    public string CreateSHA512(string strData)
    {
        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strData);
        using (var alg = SHA512.Create())
        {
            string hex = "";

            var hashValue = alg.ComputeHash(message);
            foreach (byte x in hashValue)
            {
                hex += String.Format("{0:x2}", x);
            }
            return hex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What if this answer is improved by using `var hex = new StringBuilder();` ?

Comment: Why not use Convert.ToHexString introduced in .NET 5?

Answer (score 9):

you can use this method

```
public string GetSha256Hash(string input)
{
    using (var hashAlgorithm = SHA512.Create())
    {
        var byteValue = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
        var byteHash = hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(byteValue);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(byteHash);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using RNGCryptoServiceProvider in .NET 5 but when I updated to .NET 6 I got the same warning. After reading about it in [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/40169) I changed my code from this:

```
public string HashPassword(string plainPassword)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(plainPassword))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(plainPassword));
    }

    var cryptoProvider = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] salt = new byte[SaltByteSize];
    cryptoProvider.GetBytes(salt);

    byte[] hash = GetPbkdf2Bytes(plainPassword, salt, Pbkdf2Iterations, HashByteSize);

    return $"{Pbkdf2Iterations}:{Convert.ToBase64String(salt)}:{Convert.ToBase64String(hash)}";
}
```

To this:

```
public string HashPassword(string plainPassword)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(plainPassword))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(plainPassword));
    }

    byte[] salt = RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(SaltByteSize);
    byte[] hash = GetPbkdf2Bytes(plainPassword, salt, Pbkdf2Iterations, HashByteSize);

    return $"{Pbkdf2Iterations}:{Convert.ToBase64String(salt)}:{Convert.ToBase64String(hash)}";
}
```

I know it's not exactly the same class but they are related.

Answer (score -1):

You can also based on the description of Microsoft website in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/syslib-diagnostics/syslib0021),
use this code:

```
// Disable the warning.
#pragma warning disable SYSLIB0001

// Code that uses obsolete API.
//...

// Re-enable the warning.
#pragma warning restore SYSLIB0001
```

Answer (score -1):

Same as Sike Mullivan's accepted answer, but just a little shorter:

```cs
    public string CreateSHA512(string strData)
    {
        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strData);
        using var alg = SHA512.Create();

        var hashValue = alg.ComputeHash(message);
        return hashValue.Aggregate("", (current, x) => current + $"{x:x2}");
    }
```

or, alternatively a one-liner:

```cs
public string CreateSHA512(string strData) => SHA512.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strData)).Aggregate("", (current, x) => current + $"{x:x2}");
```

Comment: One-liner is without using. It does not dispose resources on return . Also text variable is undefined